# Remotely enable and start service through CMD for entire Subnet

Tags: variables, cmd

I am trying to enable and start a service on a entire subnet. The service is called `remoteregistry`.

I would like this to apply to `192.168.100.1-192.168.100.254`.

I was able to test this out to 2 machines individually and this is what I came up with:

```
Sc \\192.168.100.100 config remoteregistry start= auto & sc \\192.168.100.100 start remoteregistry
```

I want it in a way that I wouldn't have to manually do it for each one. And if one fails for it to automatically try the next one until the subnet is complete. Maybe assigning a variable or something and doing everything through command prompt with administrative privileges. Please reply with any tips!

Comment: Use a `FOR /L` command to iterate the last octet.

Comment: It changed from disabled to enabled and from stopped to automatic which makes it start running. This is exactly what I want to do.I am stuck on how to do it for the whole subnet or multiple subnets.

Comment: Repeating @squashman `for /?` eg `for /l`.

Comment: Not sure how this <for /L> command works and how I can implement it on what I am trying to do.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed, type the command Mark gave you at the Command Prompt, and read the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file with the code below and save with .bat extension:

```
set _start_ip=192.168.100.1
set _end_ip=192.168.100.254

FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=^. " %%G IN ("%_start_ip%") DO (
    set _a=%%G
    set _b=%%H
    set _c=%%I
    set _d=%%J
)

FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=^. " %%G IN ("%_end_ip%") DO (
    set _f=%%G
)

del /f /q ip.txt

FOR /l %%G IN (%_d%,1,%_f%) DO (
    echo %_a%.%_b%.%_c%.%%~G>> ip.txt
)

FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (ip.txt) DO (
    sc \\%%G config remoteregistry start= auto & sc \\%%G start remoteregistry
)
```

Comment: So where do I add my code in here and how does my code know to pick up one IP after the next to replace the 2 IP fields on my original script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to put your code in there. In the last loop, the FOR statement iterate over a variable called %%G. So you can put your code between that parentheses and use the variable %%G in place of the IP address.